# Mechanical power during rotational motion and torque: the physical meaning of their time derivatives

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, velocity, torque, power

It is known that the mechanical power during rotational motion is defined as:

$P = M \cdot \dot{\theta}$

where $M$ is torque ($N \cdot m$) and $\dot{\theta}$ is angular velocity ($rad/s$).

If we differentiate this expression with respect to time we get the following expression:

$\dot{P}=\dot{M} \cdot \dot{\theta}+M \cdot \ddot{\theta}$

This expression contains two components, the physical meaning of which is unclear: $\dot{P}$ and $\dot{M}$. How can we explain their physical meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Power $P$ is defined as work done per time unit. You will often see it written as $\dot E$. So, a rate. We can compare it to speed, but instead of metres-moved-per-second then it would here be Joules-transferred-per-second.

$\dot P$ would be the change in this rate - the rate of a rate. We might call it the second-order gradient. Intuitively, this would represent the rate at which the energy transfer is speed up/slowed down. Compare this to acceleration, but instead of metres-per-second added each second, then it is Joules-per-second added per second.

$\dot M$ would more easily be interpreted as the rate of change in the torque.

Comment: The time derivative of torque is called _rotatum_. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotatum).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of tracking changes in power, as it can be a discontinuous function as forces/torques are discontinuous. Even if continuous it is certainly a non-differentiable function as forces and velocities can change behavior from one instant to the next.

If you want a relationship that involves **power** and **accelerations** then consider the following:

For moving rigid body take an arbitrary point **A** on the body and combine the velocity vector at this location $\boldsymbol{v}_A$ with the net torque about this point $\boldsymbol{M}_A$ to get the standard definition of (scalar) power

$$ P = \boldsymbol{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_A + \boldsymbol{M}_A \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} \tag{1} $$

where $\boldsymbol{F}$ is the force on the body, and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the rotational velocity of the body. The above relationship is invariant, which means power is the same regardless of which point **A** is chosen to sum up torques and evaluate velocity.

But there is an alternate representation of the above, considering power evaluated at the center of mass (point **C** designation) and the equations of motion $\boldsymbol{F} = m \boldsymbol{a}_C$ and $\boldsymbol{M}_C = \mathcal{I}_{C}\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathcal{I}_{C}\boldsymbol{\omega}$

If you take (1) and substitute the equation of motion you get

$$ \begin{aligned}P & =\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{C}+\boldsymbol{M}_{C}\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}\\
 & =\left(m\boldsymbol{a}_{C}\right)\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{C}+\left(\mathcal{I}_{C}\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathcal{I}_{C}\boldsymbol{\omega}\right)\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}\\
 & =m\left(\boldsymbol{a}_{C}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{C}\right)+\left(\mathcal{I}_{C}\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right)\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}\\
 & =m\left(\boldsymbol{a}_{C}\cdot\tfrac{1}{m}\boldsymbol{p}\right)+\left(\mathcal{I}_{C}\boldsymbol{\alpha}\right)\cdot\left(\mathcal{I}_{C}^{-1}\boldsymbol{L}_{C}\right)\\
 & =\boldsymbol{a}_{C}\cdot\boldsymbol{p}+\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\boldsymbol{L}_{C}
\end{aligned}
 \tag{2} $$

Where $\boldsymbol{p} = m \boldsymbol{v}_C$ is momentum and $\boldsymbol{L}_C = \mathcal{I}_C \boldsymbol{\omega}$ is angular momentum.

Because of the transformation laws, and the invariance of power $P$ the above is true at any arbitrary point also

$$ \boxed{ P =\boldsymbol{a}_{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{p}+\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\boldsymbol{L}_{A} } \tag{3}$$

Power can be considered using the combination of force and velocity **or** momentum and acceleration, for both linear and rotational systems.

This is an important relationship that helps in solving more complex systems. Given forces, and motions, momentum can be evaluated and thus accelerations can be solved for by equating (1) and (3).

Say for example you have a pivoted body at **A**, such that $\boldsymbol{v}_A =0$ as well as $\boldsymbol{a}_A=0$. In addition, you know that axis of the pivot $\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$ such that the motion is  decomposed as $\boldsymbol{\omega} = \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} \, \dot{\theta}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} \ddot{\theta}$.

The reaction moment at the pivot has a component along the axis $\tau_A$ and two components along the two perpendicular directions $\boldsymbol{\hat{i}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat{j}}$ such that $\boldsymbol{M}_A = \boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\, \tau_A + \ldots$ which don't matter because from (1) only the components along the axis count.  Combine (1) and (3) to get

$$ \require{cancel} \begin{gathered}\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\cancel{\boldsymbol{v}_{A}}+\boldsymbol{M}_{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}=\cancel{\boldsymbol{a}_{C}}\cdot\boldsymbol{p}+\boldsymbol{\alpha}\cdot\boldsymbol{L}_{A}\\
\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\tau_{A}+\ldots\right)\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\dot{\theta}\right)=\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\ddot{\theta}\right)\cdot\boldsymbol{L}_{A} \\
\tau_{A}\dot{\theta}=\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\cdot\boldsymbol{L}_{A}\right)\ddot{\theta}\\
\ddot{\theta}=\frac{\tau_{A}\dot{\theta}}{\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\cdot\boldsymbol{L}_{A}}=\frac{\tau_{A}\dot{\theta}}{\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\cdot\left(\mathcal{I}_{A}\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\dot{\theta}\right)}=\frac{\tau_{A}}{I_{z}} 
\end{gathered} $$

where $I_z = \boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\cdot\left(\mathcal{I}_{A}\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\right)$ is the component of mass moment of inertia tensor $\mathcal{I}_A$ along the pivot axis

This is quite powerful because all you need to find rotational acceleration is angular momentum about the pivot.

If you are doing the dynamics for many system you can state one of the two following (scalar) expressions and it will give you the equations of motion

$$ \begin{aligned}
\text{acceleration} & = \frac{ \text{power}}{\text{momentum}} \\
\text{rotational acceleration} & = \frac{ \text{power}}{\text{angualar momentum}} \end{aligned} \tag{4}$$

The simplest example is the acceleration of a car under fixed power $P$ and having drag force $F_{\rm drag}$

$$ a_{\rm car} = \frac{ P - F_{\rm drag} v_{\rm car}}{m_{\rm car} v_{\rm car}} = \frac{\text{power}}{\text{momentum}} $$

another example is a bead that is sliding on a rotating rod, under the influence of a pivot torque $\tau_{\rm pivot}$

[image: fig1]

The rotational acceleration is given by

$$ \ddot{\theta} = \frac{ \tau_{\rm pivot} \dot{\theta} }{I_{\rm pivot} \dot{\theta}} = \frac{ \tau_{\rm pivot} }{ I_{\rm pivot} } $$

At the same time the (scalar) acceleration is given by

$$ \dot{v} = \frac{ \tau_{\rm pivot} \dot{\theta}} { m v } $$

If you take the above example and want to see the effects of adding a radial force $F_{\rm radial}$ along the distance $r$, then you just update the numerator with the new power value. The

$$ \dot{v} = \frac{ \tau_{\rm pivot} \dot{\theta} + F_{\rm radial}\,\dot{r}} { m v } $$

In summary, expression (3) is what you want to use to find accelerations that result of adding or removing power from a system. But it only works to get the acceleration component parallel to the momentum component evaluated.